# Jenkins debuting ERROR No iOS profile matching found

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, jenkins, provisioning-profile

When debugging iOS from jenkins, I get the following error.

=== BUILD TARGET 'myTargetName' OF PROJECT 'projectName' WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
No iOS profile matching 'provisiongName' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'provisiongName'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

Please tell me how to fix it...please.

Comment: Did you solve it? I ran into the same issue